# LINQ concatenating elements in two string arrays

Tags: c#

I have two string arrays

```
Array1 = {"Paul","John","Mary"}
Array2 = {"12","13","15"}
```

I would like to know whether it is possible to join these arrays so that the resultant arrays have something like

```
{"Paul12","John13","Mary15"}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
 var Array3 = Array1.Zip(Array2, (a, b) => a + b).ToList();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx).

```
var array1 = new[] {"Paul", "John", "Mary"};
var array2 = new[] {"12", "13", "15"};

var result = array1.Zip(array2, (a1, a2) => String.Concat(a1, a2)).ToArray();
```