# How can combine two enumerations with a custom function?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, enumeration

Given are two `IEnumerable<A> a` and `IEnumerable<B> b`. It is guaranteed that they are of the same length. I would like to create a new `IEnumerable<C> c` in which each item `c_i` is derived using a `Func<A, B, C> f` by `c_i := f (a_i, b_i)`.

The best I could come up with is manual simultaneous enumeration over both sources and yield-ing the current result, implemented as an extension method. Is there a short way to do it without custom code in .NET >= 4.0?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ concatenating elements in two string arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101333/linq-concatenating-elements-in-two-string-arrays)

Comment: Thanks all, I don't know how I could miss that :)

Comment: This is certainly a duplicate, though I find this question to be easier to find using search. How should we deal with this?

Comment: Mark the other question as a duplicate of this one and see who wins? :) Actually I'm not really sure :\ It's unfortunate that we can't undo close votes. If it gets closed, I'll at least vote to reopen it.

Comment: Indeed, policy is to close the original per http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75885/what-if-the-duplicate-is-better-than-the-original

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx).

e.g.

```
var c = a.Zip(b, (a, b) => SomeFunc(a, b));
```

Comment: Zip() is great, but be careful because it stops when it reaches the end of the shorter input enumerable, which may produce unexpected results if you don't know this is going to happen

Answer (score 5):

Use `Zip` method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx

> Applies a specified function to the corresponding elements of two
>   sequences, producing a sequence of the results.

```
    int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    string[] words = { "one", "two", "three" };

    var numbersAndWords = numbers.Zip(words, (first, second) => first + " " + second);

    foreach (var item in numbersAndWords)
        Console.WriteLine(item);

    // This code produces the following output: 

    // 1 one 
    // 2 two 
    // 3 three
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Enumerable.Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx). Given a function `f(A, B)`, you would have

```
var c = a.Zip(b, (aItem, bItem) => f(aItem, bItem));
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution to the Zip extension method can be achieved using nested Select and SelectMany to flatten the result. The implementation should take only the elements with the same index in the list (not the cross product):

```
private int fun(int a, int b)
{
    return a * b;
}

var l1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var l2 = new List<int> { 4, 5, 6 };

var r = l1.Select((e1, i1) => l2.Select ((e2, i2) => i1 == i2 ? fun(e1, e2) : 0))
        .SelectMany (flat => flat)
        .Where(re => re != 0)
        .ToList();
```

The output in this case is:

```
4 
10 
18
```

Comment: -1: This produces a cross-product of the elements, which is not what the OP was looking for.

Comment: @Cory Yeah, sorry, i should read more carefully. I changed the code in my answer to bring the same result as the Zip method - it takes only the same indices ;-)